# 2D array visualization in Visual Studio Code

Tags: debugging, multidimensional-array, visual-studio-code

During debugging C code in Visual Studio Code, I would like to display all elements of 2D arrays to see all rows and columns. What is the simple way to do this? Is there any available plugin to do this? I think about something like Visual Studio Array Visualizer:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AmirLiberman.ArrayVisualizer

but for Visual Studio Code.